# adb.exe: error: cannot bind listener: Operation not permitted

Tags: android-studio, adb

I want to connect the emulator with back-end app on own local machine by using command:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8085 tcp:8085
```

But It return results:

```
adb.exe: error: cannot bind listener: Operation not permitted.
```

Please help me how to solve it.

I am using Android studio, my backend run node

Comment: I have a similar problem on linux. Looking through some logs I see:
`06-12 16:16:04.412  1785  1785 E netmgr  : Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument`

though I'm not sure if that's the actual cause of the issue.

Comment: do you figure this out?

Comment: thanks @MikeH-R, I found the cause. when i use android emulator with API level 28, it works and I don't understand why.

Comment: FWIW I also was getting the same thing with and AVD with latest Android (Q 29). Installing Pie 28 instead fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just posting the answer based on what is written in the comments by @user3647475 for anyone who is facing the issue

This issue occurs on AVDs running on android platform api version 29 - I am not sure what is the root cause.

Quick fix is to create & use avd with android platform api version 28, and re-test.

I tested on the android Asus phone running on android platform api version 29 and I did not face this issue.

So seems like there is a problem with the avd/system images made up of android platform api version 29

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, i followed this steps and it worked

```sh
adb root
adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```